# Highcharts display barchart locally (localhost) but not online (web host)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I use Highchart js to display bar chart from MySQL database using PHP.
This thing ***works perfectly*** on my computer while coding it. But it doesn't when I host the files online.

**Database connection:**

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql3 = 'SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN jk="0" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as jumlahwanita, SUM(CASE WHEN jk="1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as jumlahlaki, star as star'
        . ' FROM pstrating'
        . ' GROUP BY star'
        . ' ORDER BY star ASC';

$hasil3 = $conn->query($sql3);
?>
```

**Assigning the array:**

```
<?php
$label = array();
$nilailaki = array();
$nilaiwanita = array();
foreach ($hasil3 as $i => $ii) {
    $label[$i] = array($ii['star']);
    $nilaiwanita[$i] = (int) $ii['jumlahwanita'];
    $nilailaki[$i] = (int) $ii['jumlahlaki'];
}
?>
```

**Displaying data using javascript (inside `<body>` tags):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Create the chart
        Highcharts.chart('dataProvider', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                /*backgroundColor: '#E8FFD1',*/
                style: {
                    fontFamily: '"Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif', // default font
                    fontSize: '1em'
                },
            },
            title: {
                text: 'PRESTASI LAYANAN PST'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Berdasarkan Penilaian Pengguna (Range nilai 0-5)'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories:
                        [<?php
                                                $arrlength = count($label);
                                                for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
                                                    echo '"' . $label[$x][0] . '"' . ", ";
                                                }
                                                ?>],
                title: {
                    text: 'Rating'
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'JUMLAH RATING',
                    align: 'middle'
                }

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    },
                },
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<table>' +
                        '<b><i>Rating: {point.key}</span></i></b>'
                ,
                pointFormat: '<tr>' +
                        '<td style="color:{series.color};font-weight:bold">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td> : </td>' +
                        '<td style="font-weight:bold">{point.y} kali</td>' +
                        '</tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Perempuan',
                    data: [<?php echo $nilaiwanita[0] . ',' . $nilaiwanita[1]; ?>],
                    color: '#E78DF9'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Laki-laki',
                    data: [<?php echo join($nilailaki, ',') ?>],
                    color: '#438EFA'
                }
            ],
        });
    });

</script>
```

I tried changing the `series` property using `[1,2,3,6,1]` and it then displayed the data. But using this `data: [<?php echo join($nilailaki, ',') ?>],` or this `[<?php echo $nilaiwanita[0] . ',' . $nilaiwanita[1]; ?>],` doesn't show anything.

I also tried accessing the js file on my web host and it shows just fine.
I don't understand what doesn't work here.

**The chart display on web host:**
[image: Display on Web Host]

**The chart display on my local computer:**
[image: Display on Local]

Comment: It would be good to check the PHP versions of your local version and your hosted version

Comment: do you get any error in the server log ? is the data the same ?

Comment: By comparing those two pictures, I can say that in the one you do not load any data at all. You can try to invesigate the web source code (js + html only) or paste it here.

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ there is no error at all on my browser console. That's why I'm really confused.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius on my local I have version 5.4.7 and on the web host it has version 5.3.29. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @morganfree If I understand your instruction, this is what it shows when I hit ctrl+u on my chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/2vs027z4/ I need help please.

Comment: Your data is empty for one serie and only 0 for the other so you will not see anything in the chart. Are you sure your database contains the same data ?

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ I am absolutely sure that the data is the same. This is the hosted website if you'd like to see: http://bengkulucommunity.web.id/pstsurvey/rinci.php, the data on the table below the graph is retrieved from the same database, with the same connection.

Comment: @Safira Those version difference arent substantial enough to make a huge difference but its something to keep in mind for any future problems that occur! | If youre using chrome then you should use chrome dev tools to break down the problem

Comment: As @morganfree says before, it looks like the chart series has no data. Are you sure that your php is parsed correctly? Maybe could you try to display the code from this php part?